# Concatenacion junto a un bucle para generar una serie abecedarica

Tags: python

La idea es la siguiente. Los nombres de los patitos son: Jack, Kack, Lack, Mack, Nack, Ouack, Pack, y Quack.

```py
prefijos= "JKLMNOPQ"
sufijo= "ack"

for letra in prefijos:
       print letra + sufijo
```

La salida del programa es:
Jack
Kack
Lack
Mack 
Nack 
Oack 
Pack 
Qack

Basicamente las palabras que empiezan con "Q" y "O", deberian terminar con el sufijo "uack" y no "ack"

```py
prefijos = "JKLMNOPQ"
sufijo = "ack"
sufijoextra = "uack"

def recorrido():
    for letra in prefijos:
        if letra == "O" or "Q":
            print (letra + sufijoextra)
        else:
            print (letra + sufijo)


recorrido()
```

Pero sin embargo no logro tener la salida correcta. Me salen todos con terminacion "uack".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

el error está en la condición del `if`.

Tienes: `if letra == "O" or "Q":`

Debería ser: `if letra == "O" or letra == "Q":`

Otra opción (que yo preferiría) es `if letra in [ "O", "Q" ]:`

Quedaría así:

```
prefijos = "JKLMNOPQ"
sufijo = "ack"
sufijoextra = "uack"

def recorrido():
    for letra in prefijos:
        if letra in [ "O", "Q"]:
            print (letra + sufijoextra)
        else:
            print (letra + sufijo)


recorrido()
```

Comment: +1 Otra opción más compacta: `if letra in "OQ"`